# What could cause an ORA-00936 - Missing Expression with the following sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

We're seeing the error message ORA-00936 Missing Expression for the following SQL:

Note that this is just a cut-down version of a much bigger SQL so rewriting it to a inner join or similar is not really in the scope of this:

This is the SQL that fails:

```
select (select count(*) from gt_roster where ROS_ROSTERPLAN_ID = RPL_ID)
from gt_rosterplan
where RPL_ID = 432065061
```

What I've tried:
* Extracting the innermost SQL and substituting the ID from the outer SQL gives me the number 12.
* Aliasing both the sub-query, and the count(*) individually and both at the same time does not change the outcome (ie. still an error)

What else do I need to look at?

The above are only tables, no views, RPL_ID is primary key of gt_rosterplan, and ROS_ROSTERPLAN_ID is a foreign key to this column, there is basically no magic or hidden information here.

---

**Edit:** In response to answer, no, you do not need the aliases here as the columns are uniquely named across the tables.

---

**Solved:** The problem was that the client was running the wrong client driver version, 9.2.0.1, and there are known problems with that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, assuming the column names are not ambiguous (and even if they were that would lead to a different error).  I ran an equivalent statement and got a result without error:

```
SQL> select (select count(*) from emp2 where empdeptno = deptno)
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno=10
  4  /

(SELECTCOUNT(*)FROMEMP2WHEREEMPDEPTNO=DEPTNO)
---------------------------------------------
                                            3
```

Googling it appears that there are or have been Oracle bugs leading to ORA-00936 errors - see [this for example](http://oracle-error.blogspot.com/2008/04/ora-00936missing-expression.html).

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the client was running the wrong client driver version, 9.2.0.1, and there are known problems with that version.